# How to use grep or awk to print between a string and a variable

Tags: bash, awk, sed

What's the correct way to use sed or awk to output text between a string and a variable?

This doesn't seem to work

```
firstline=<item rdf:about="https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2015-1977"

wget -qO- https://nvd.nist.gov/download/nvd-rss-analyzed.xml | sed -n '/<item /,/"$firstline"/p' > output
```

$firstline holds a value from previous wget fetch

Edit: Question clarified

Comment: Use `sed -n "/<item /,/$firstline/p"`

Comment: when I execute `firstline=<item rdf:about="https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2015-1977"`, i get error msg "-ksh: item: cannot open [No such file or directory]". is it different in `bash`? Good luck to all.

Comment: I also noticed that I get following error
sed: -e expression #1, char 35: unknown command: `/'

Comment: This error comes because of the slashes "/"
Is there way to escape them?

Comment: To escape all slashes `/` in a variable in bash is as simple as `${firstline//\//\\/}` which will result in all `/` becoming `\/`.

Comment: Code with glaing syntax errors and no clear intent are an awful way of explaining what you are trying to accomplish. Voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed this way is not correct, **sed does not re-match the second address** against the `pattern space` (simply said just the current line if you not hold to `hold space` and then get it to `pattern space`) that **matched the first address**.

The first address is `<item` and the second address start with `<item ..`. So you will never matched the second address even though you escaped the special characters in second address.

Using line number to select content:

```
$ wget -qO- https://nvd.nist.gov/download/nvd-rss-analyzed.xml > result
$ firstline="<item rdf:about=\"https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2015-1977\""
$ echo $firstline
<item rdf:about="https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2015-1977"
$ start=$(grep -n "<item " result | head -n1 | awk -F\: '{print $1}')
$ end=$(grep -n "$(echo $firstline | sed 's/\//\\&/g')" result | awk -F\: '{print $1}')
echo $start $end
169 187 
$ sed -n "$start,${end}p" result > output
```

Another method using two adresses:

```
$ wget -qO- https://nvd.nist.gov/download/nvd-rss-analyzed.xml > result
$ firstline="<item rdf:about=\"https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2015-1977\""
$ firstline=$(echo $firstline | sed 's/\//\\&/g')
$ cat result | sed -n "/<item /,\${p; /$firstline/q;}"
  <item rdf:about="https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2007-3701">
  ...
  <item rdf:about="https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2015-1977">
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use shell variables in sed. Just use double quote instead of single quote.

And the error you met,you should use backslash to convert it. Also the error you met need you to add a backslash at the end of each line.

```
wget xxxxx|sed 's/$/&\\/g'  >temp
sed -i "/<item /,/$firstline/p" temp
```

Now the result will store in the temp file.